# SUMIF Not working in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Found the problem, but not a way to fix it.

I'm European and we use , instead of . to show decimals.
so 2,50 euros for example is a value.

How can i have a formula like `=SUMIF(E:E, "A", I:I)` (Get the sum of I where the E column value is "A")  work using comma's instead of points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your spreadsheet is in a locale that uses comma as decimal mark, use semicolon `;` as formula argument separator instead of comma `,`, like this:

```
=sumif(E1:E; "A"; I1:I)
```

Use **File > Settings > Locale** to set your spreadsheet's locale correctly. Note that this also sets things like date and time format, and timezone, which may cause existing date and time values to shift.

For more information, see [Set a spreadsheet’s location & calculation settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cchange-locale-and-time-zone) and this [blog post by Ben Collins](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/).

Comment: You my friend, have earned your cookie :) Thanks!